# Proving: $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \ f(x)=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \ f(1/t)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

Please advise: is my proof sufficient? or do I need to use $\epsilon$?

Prove that $$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \ f(x)=
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \ f(1/t)$$ if these limits exist

Proof: putting $t=\dfrac{1}{x}$ then as $x\to\infty, \ t\to0^+$ and $x=\dfrac{1}{t}$

Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0^+} \ f(1/t)$

Comment: While what you wrote is indeed the idea behind what's happening, I would be willing to bet money that whoever gave you that assignment expects you to use $\epsilon$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316880/limit-of-fx-and-f1-x)

Answer (score 0):

This is just exercise 75 in Section 2.7, James Stewart, *Calculus Early Transcendentals* 7th ed. 2011. Page 143.

Note that this result is true for $x \rightarrow -\infty$ and $t \rightarrow 0^-$ also.

[image]