# How do we go from $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\sin{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, proof-explanation

From Spivak's *Calculus*, Ch. 15 "Trigonometric Functions"

20. Find $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$.

The solution manuals says simply

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\sin{x}=1$

What is the exact manipulation at the $\epsilon$ $\delta$ level that allows us to change the form of the limit?

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}=l$ means

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists M>0\ \forall x, x>M\implies |x\sin{1/x}-l|<\epsilon$$

Let $y=\frac{1}{x}>0$.

Then for some $\epsilon>0$ there is an $M>0$ such that $\forall y$ such that $y=\frac{1}{x}$ we have

$$\left (y=\frac{1}{x}>M>0\implies 0<x<\frac{1}{M} \right )\implies \left |y\sin{\frac{1}{y}}-l \right |<\epsilon\implies \left |\frac{1}{x}\sin{x}-l \right |$$

Therefore, we are saying that for any $x$ we can form a $y$ larger than $M$, and this happens when $x$ is smaller than $1/M$ and this leads to $\left |\frac{1}{x}\sin{x}-l \right |$.

Therefore,

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<x<\delta \implies \left |\frac{1}{x}\sin{x}-l \right |$$

This sort of thing really makes my head spin. Is it really this difficult to grasp such manipulations? **Are the manipulations of the initial limit above correct?**

At this point we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\sin{x}=l$$

And this limit we can solve by L'Hôpital's Rule

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\sin{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\cos{x}}{1}=1$$

Comment: simple, take x=1/t

Comment: Simple but can you actually explain what is happening when you do that, in a didactical way?

Comment: I mean... what more are you looking for?

Comment: You should avoid l"Hospital rule. The last limit is by definition equal to the derivative of $\sin x$ at $x=0.$ So your reasoning becomes circular.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316880/42969

Answer (score 3):

I propose that instead of focusing on $x \sin x^{-1}$, we focus on a general function $f$.

We wish to show that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+} f\left(\frac1x \right) = L$. The former gives us that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $x > N$. Similarly, we want to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f\left( \frac1x \right) - L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $0 \le x < \delta$. This is equivalent to saying that if $0 \le \frac1x < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. Since $1/x < \delta$, we have that $x > \frac1\delta$. Therefore, choose $\delta = \frac1N$. Right now, we have shown that $\lim_{\frac1x \to 0^+} f(x) = L$, but let $y = \frac1x$, and we get $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) = L$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

The most didactic (in my opinion)  is the following
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}t\,\sin (t^{-1})=\lim_{t\to \infty}{\sin (t^{-1})\over t^{-1}}\ \underset{x=t^{-1}}{=}\ \lim_{x\to 0^+}{\sin x\over x}=1$$

More formally, the composition rule has been applied. Namely if $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=b,$ $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}g(t)=a$ and $g(t)>a$ then
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}f(g(t))=b$$
In our case $g(t)=t^{-1},$  $f(x)=x^{-1}\sin x$ and $a=0,$ $b=1.$ I leave $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}t^{-1}=0$ as an easy fact.

The fastest way of proving the composition rule is by applying the Heine definition of the limit.

Comment: You can't casually sub limits for limits. It can work for explanatory purposes, though.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost That is typically when people say "hold my beer" ;)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven LMAO! No contention, you lot probably know more than me. :'D

Answer (score 0):

Consider functions $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)$ depicted below

[image]

The little arrow tips are just my way of showing where limits are being taken.

We have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x)=L \tag{1}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(1/x)=L\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ means

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N>0\ \forall x, x>N>0\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon\tag{3}$$

For a given $\epsilon>0$ we are looking at values of $x$ above a certain $N$.

If instead of writing a number as $x$ we write it as a multiplicative inverse $x^{-1}$ of some number $x$, then we have

$$0<N<\frac{1}{x}\implies 0<x<\frac{1}{N}\implies \left |f\left (\frac{1}{x}\right )-L\right |<\epsilon\implies |g(x)-L|<\epsilon \tag{4}$$

We can interpret $(4)$ in two ways

1. for numbers $x^{-1}$ above $N$, $f$ evaluated at such numbers is close to $L$
2. for numbers $x$ smaller than $\frac{1}{N}$, the function $g$ is close to $L$